# Unity with factory method who need parameters

Tags: c#, unity-container, factory

I want to register a type in an Unity container with a factory method who needs paramters. These parameters are to be resolved by unity but only at runtime.

Factory method code :

```
public static IApp Create(IOne, ITwo) {...}
```

Register code :

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IApp), new InjectionFactory(f => App.Create(???, ???)));
```

What do I need to replace the '???' ?

More informations :

My Unity configuration is made in two phases. First phase (application is starting), I register all my object but one :

```
container.RegisterType<IOne, One>();
container.RegisterType<ITwo, Two>();
container.RegisterType<IApp, App>();
// ...
```

Phase two (user is logging), I juste register an instance of a context object who is used in constructor of all my classes (`One`, `Two`, `App`, ...) :

```
var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
childContainer.RegisterInstance<AppEnvironment>(new AppEnvironment(userName));
```

This is my code without using InjectionFactory. It works fine. Now, I have to register multiple times my IApp interface, with calling a different static method each time. Example of static method :

```
public static IApp Create(IOne one, ITwo two, AppEnvironment env) 
{
    _one = one;
    _two = two;
    _env = env;
}
```

If I register IApp this this code :

```
container.Register(typeof(IApp), new InjectionFactory(f => App.Create(container.Resolve<IOne>(), container.Resolve<ITwo>(), container.Resolve<AppEnvironment>()));
```

Then my env variable is not set.

But if I register my env instance (just for test purpose, I can't do that in my case), it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got the solution. It looks like willys one :

```
container.RegisterType<IApp, App>(
    new InjectionFactory(
        f => App.Create(
            f.Resolve<IOne>(), 
            f.Resolve<ITwo>()
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IApp),
    new InjectionFactory(f => App.Create(
        container.Resolve<IOne>(), 
        container.Resolve<ITwo>())));
```

Comment: As I say, these dependencies are to be resolved at runtime.

Comment: yes but these interfaces are resolved with another dependency (a kind of context) who is registered in Unity later in the flow. So when the instances are created, the "context" object is not the good one.

Comment: Since `IOne` and `ITwo` are resolved in lambda passed to `InjectionFactory`, they will actually be resolved during `IApp` resolve.

Comment: Yes, they are (I put a breackpoint to be sure), but they don't care about another dependency who is register later...

Comment: Could you provide more minimal verifiable example?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this Interface/Class :

```
public interface IApp { }
public class App : IApp
{
    public App(IOne iOneInstance, ITwo iTwoInstance) { /* Irrelevant */}
}

public interface IOne { }
public class OneA : IOne { }
public class OneB : IOne { }
public interface ITwo { }
public class TwoA : ITwo { }
public class TwoB : ITwo { }
```

Let's make that your class with the factory method. **You wouldn't use both of these**, only one version :

```
// Version One
public class ClassWithFactoryMethodOne
{
    Func<IOne, ITwo, IApp> iAppFactory;
    public ClassWithFactoryMethodOne(Func<IOne, ITwo, IApp> iAppFactory)
    {
        this.iAppFactory = iAppFactory;
    }

    public IApp Create(IOne iOneInstance, ITwo iTwoInstance)
    {
        return this.iAppFactory(iOneInstance, iTwoInstance);
    }
}

// Version Two
public class ClassWithFactoryMethodTwo
{
    Func<string, string, IApp> iAppFactory;
    ClassWithFactoryMethodTwo(Func<string, string, IApp> iAppFactory)
    {
        this.iAppFactory = iAppFactory;
    }

    public IApp Create(string iOneNamedRegistration, string iTwoNamedRegistration)
    {
        return this.iAppFactory(iOneNamedRegistration, iTwoNamedRegistration);
    }
}
```

If you do the registrations like this, it should work :

```
class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IOne, OneA>("A");
        container.RegisterType<IOne, OneB>("B");
        container.RegisterType<ITwo, TwoA>("A");
        container.RegisterType<ITwo, TwoB>("B");

        container.RegisterType<Func<IOne, ITwo, IApp>>(
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
                new Func<IOne, ITwo, IApp>((iOne, iTwo) =>
                    c.Resolve<IApp>(
                        new ParameterOverride("iOneInstance", iOne),
                        new ParameterOverride("iTwoInstance", iTwo)))));

        container.RegisterType<Func<string, string, IApp>>(
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
                new Func<string, string, IApp>((iOneNamedRegistration, iTwoNamedRegistration) =>
                    c.Resolve<IApp>(
                        new ParameterOverride("iOneInstance", c.Resolve<IOne>(iOneNamedRegistration)),
                        new ParameterOverride("iTwoInstance", c.Resolve<ITwo>(iTwoNamedRegistration))))));

        // Alternate writing
        container.RegisterType<Func<string, string, IApp>>(
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
                new Func<string, string, IApp>((iOneNamedRegistration, iTwoNamedRegistration) =>
                {
                    IOne iOne = c.Resolve<IOne>(iOneNamedRegistration);
                    ITwo iTwo = c.Resolve<ITwo>(iTwoNamedRegistration);

                    IApp iApp = c.Resolve<IApp>(
                        new ParameterOverride("iOneInstance", iOne),
                        new ParameterOverride("iTwoInstance", iTwo));

                    return iApp;
                })));

        ClassWithFactoryMethodOne versionOne = container.Resolve<ClassWithFactoryMethodOne>();
        // Somewhere you have logic and end up with instances of IOne and ITwo then you :
        IApp iApp1 = versionOne.Create(iOneInstance, iTwoInstance); // This doesn't compile cause you'd need the instances.

        ClassWithFactoryMethodTwo versionTwo = container.Resolve<ClassWithFactoryMethodTwo>();
        IApp iApp2 = versionTwo.Create("A", "B");
    }
}
```

I think that if I explain the `// Alternate Writing` I wrote in the `Main` method, it will clear up some things :

When you use `new InjectionFactory`, you write a lambda expression that will receive an `IUnityContainer` as parameter (which I named `c`.) That expression is used to create the factory itself. In the factory, which has access to `c`, I then `IOne iOne = c.Resolve<IOne>(iOneNamedRegistration);`, hence asking the *container* to resolve an IOne, using the first *named registration* that the factory will have received. The same thing for ITwo. Then, I ask the *container* to resolve an `IApp` for me, overriding the parameter named `iOneInstance` with the instance of `IOne`, and same for `ITwo`.

Oh, and the last lines in the method would be just how you'd actually call the `Create` methods. The 2nd one would ask the instance of `ClassWithFactoryMethodTwo` to create an `IApp` with an `IOne` that is actually a `OneA`, and an `ITwo` that is actually a `TwoB`.

Anything left unclear?

Comment: your code doesn't compile. The error is `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionConstructor' to 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride'`. And I don't really understand what I'm doing, so it's hard to debug...

Comment: I've updated the code so it compiles. I'll complete the example so you better understand. If I can manage it, I'll try to explain some parts of it better.