# Unity container resolve based on attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container, cqrs

I am writing an application that has difference class implementations for different clients. We are using CQRS and i want to add a different implementation of commands and queries for each client (or default to default one if no client specific one exists).

The application was previously written to only have one client and this works fine, but now we need the commands and clients overridden for each client. I have toyed with many ideas on how to do this, but this feels the cleanest as new clients could be added easily by just adding a set of queries/commands.

The code that dispatches the queries is below:

```
 public InProcQueryDispatcher(
        IQueryHandlerFactory queryHandlerFactory,
        Action<Exception, IQuery> onHandlerFailed)
    {
        this.queryHandlerFactory = queryHandlerFactory;
        this.onHandlerFailed = onHandlerFailed;
        this.getHandlerMethod = typeof(IQueryHandlerFactory).GetMethod("GetHandler");
    }

    public async Task<TResult> Execute<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        try
        {
            var queryHandler = this.ResolveHandler<TResult>(query.GetType());

            var task = (Task<TResult>) queryHandler.Handle((dynamic) query);

            return await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.onHandlerFailed(ex, query);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private dynamic ResolveHandler<TResult>(Type queryType)
    {
        var getHandler = this.getHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(queryType, typeof (TResult));
        return getHandler.Invoke(this.queryHandlerFactory, null);
    }
}
```

I now want to be able to change it as follows:

```
`public async Task<TResult> Execute<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
        {
            if (query == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            try
            {
                var queryHandler = this.ResolveHandler<TResult>(query.GetType(), query.ClientId);

                var task = (Task<TResult>) queryHandler.Handle((dynamic) query);

                return await task;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.onHandlerFailed(ex, query);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private dynamic ResolveHandler<TResult>(Type queryType, Guid clientId)
        {
            var getHandler = this.getHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(queryType, clientId, typeof (TResult));
            return getHandler.Invoke(this.queryHandlerFactory, null);
        }
```

Can anyone recommend how I could update my getHandleMethod to resolve the correct query based on the clientID?

GetHandleMethod:

```
 public IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> GetHandler<TQuery, TResult>() where TQuery : class, IQuery<TResult>
    {
        return container.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With IoC, your objects shouldn't be *aware* of the container itself, in the sense that you're right not to pass the container straight to the constructor. You could, however, pass a factory to your class, which it would then use to resolve. I found that combining that with named registrations works pretty well. A summary of how you could do it would be something along the lines of :

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>, QueryHandlerVersionOne<TQuery, TResult>>("1");
container.RegisterType<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>, QueryHandlerVersionTwo<TQuery, TResult>>("2");

container.RegisterType<Func<int, IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>>(
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
        new Func<int, IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>((clientID) =>
        {
            var handler = c.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>(clientID.ToString());

            return handler;
        })));
```

And then, in your constructor, you add a parameter for the factory's injection of type `Func<int, IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>`.

I answered with a longer example [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390927/unity-with-factory-method-who-need-parameters/43395688#43395688).